# Strange issue with setting visibility collapsed in grid (c#, xaml, UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, uwp

I'm trying to make a Grid that has options to choose the number of players (up to six) and input names in TextBoxes. There are "+" and "-" buttons under the grid that will add or remove a player (it starts with two). Everything works fine until you add the 6th player and then try to subtract 1 player. The Player 6 Textbox and Name input Textbox stay visible, replacing the Player 5 ones. Here is the xaml

```
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="800" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--Headers-->
            <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text=""/>
            <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" Margin="20,0,20,0" TextAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Name="PlayerOneTag" Text="Player 1" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerTwoTag" Text="Player 2" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerThreeTag" Text="Player 3" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerFourTag" Text="Player 4" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerFiveTag" Text="Player 5" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerSixTag" Text="Player 6" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20,40,20" TextAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

            <TextBox Name="PlayerOneName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBox Name="PlayerTwoName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBox Name="PlayerThreeName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBox Name="PlayerFourName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBox Name="PlayerFiveName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBox Name="PlayerSixName" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                <StackPanel Name="PlayerTwoButtons"  Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="AddPlayerThreeButton" Tapped="AddPlayerThree" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlusButton}" Visibility="Visible"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Name="PlayerThreeButtons"  Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="MinusPlayerThreeButton" Tapped="MinusPlayerThree"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MinusButton}" />
                    <Button Name="AddPlayerFourButton" Tapped="AddPlayerFour"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlusButton}" />

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel  Name="PlayerFourButtons" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Button Name="MinusPlayerFourButton" Tapped="MinusPlayerFour"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MinusButton}"/>
                    <Button Name="AddPlayerFiveButton" Tapped="AddPlayerFive"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlusButton}" />

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Name="PlayerFiveButtons" Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Button Name="MinusPlayerFiveButton" Tapped="MinusPlayerFive"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MinusButton}" />
                    <Button Name="AddPlayerSixButton" Tapped="AddPlayerSix"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlusButton}"  />

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Name="PlayerSixButtons" Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Button Name="MinusPlayerSixButton" Tapped="MinusPlayerSix"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MinusButton}" />

                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
```

And here is the C# code behind

```
private void AddPlayerThree(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerThreeName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerThreeTag.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerTwoButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerThreeButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void AddPlayerFour(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerFourName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerFourTag.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerThreeButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFourButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void AddPlayerFive(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerFiveName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerFiveTag.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerFourButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFiveButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void AddPlayerSix(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerSixName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerSixTag.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        AddPlayerSixButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MinusPlayerSixButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void MinusPlayerThree(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerThreeName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerThreeTag.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerThreeButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerTwoButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;     

    }

    private void MinusPlayerFour(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerFourName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFourTag.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFourButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerThreeButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }

    private void MinusPlayerFive(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerFiveName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFiveTag.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFiveButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFourButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


    }

    private void MinusPlayerSix(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerSixTag.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerSixName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerSixButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerFiveButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this and I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add player 6, you're not doing the same things as in the other buttons' clicks (I compared the different button clicks/taps, then saw the problem). In `AddPlayerSix` you worked directly on the Buttons, instead of on the StackPanels. The code below works:

```
private void AddPlayerSix(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        PlayerSixName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PlayerSixTag.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // Your code (not working)
        //AddPlayerSixButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //MinusPlayerSixButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // New code (works)
        PlayerFiveButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PlayerSixButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you!! I knew it was going to be something really dumb. I appreciate it!